# XCode Design - How to create a map?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview

So I basically have a bunch of routes (think of 3D positions) and I'd like to draw them in a view.

I haven't actually done anything w/graphics before and was curious how I should even start thinking about doing this in XCode w/my Cocoa app.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Should I subclass NSView? Should I use OpenGL?

Thanks!

Edit: So I was able to subclass NSView, see here: http://groovyape.com/map.png

Is this the best way? (I realize it's only 2D, I'm afraid to try 3D heh).  And what if i want to allow people to click on the circles - how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NSView subclass you can override the various mouse event handlers to do whatever you want:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event;
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event;
```

Then you'll need a way to know where the circles are so you'll know when they've been clicked in. If you have a circle as an NSPoint and the radius then something like this will work

```
- (BOOL)isPoint:(NSPoint)click inCircleAtPoint:(NSPoint)centre withRadius:(float)r
{
    float dx = click.x - centre.x;
    float dy = click.y - centre.y;

    // Get the distance from the click to the centre of the circle
    float h = hypot (dx, dy);

    // is the distance less than the radius?
    return (h < r);
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSPoint clickPoint = [event locationInWindow];

    if ([self isPoint:clickPoint inCircleAtPoint:mapPoint withRadius:5.0]) {
        // Click was in point
    }
}
```